# How to clean 'forloop.counter' variable (reset variable to 1)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

in my database there are customers and each customer have sensors. For example customers 1 have 2 sensors. am gettin sensors infos and put them separately in tables. but items's ID (NO) is wrong. please take a look to pic1
[image: pic1]

as coding, i use standard django template filters.

```
{% for info in infos %}
   ......
   ......
  <span> {{ forloop.counter }} </span>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Does that number come DB id?

Comment: show your full html code

Comment: is the ID in database 1,2,3, Check ID in database first

Comment: none. ID dose not coming from DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to sort your `infos` queryset according to the sensor name using orderby https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by. Then you can use Javascript with django template tags to achieve

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sensor_name = "";
    var counter = 1;

    {% for info in infos %}
    if (sensor_name != {{info.name}}) {
        sensor_name = {{info.name}};
        counter = 1;
    }
    else {
        counter += 1;
    }
    $("span").text(counter); //this is your span where you show the sensor number

    {% endfor %}
</script>
```